# Java Socket no exception raised when server down

Tags: java, sockets, exception

Can someone give me some support on this : I have these client and server socket classes :

```
public class Client {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String servername = "localhost";
        int port = 21000;
        Socket sc = null;
        boolean test = true;

        while(test) {
            try {
                sc = new Socket(servername, port);
                PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(sc.getOutputStream(), true);
                for(int i = 0; i < 100 ; i++) {
                    out.println("number " + i + " transmitted !");
                    System.out.println("number " + i + " transmitted !");
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                test = false;
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
                try {
                    sc.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                continue;
            }
        }
    }
}


public class Server {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int port = 21000;

        try(ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
            Socket sc = serverSocket.accept();
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(sc.getInputStream())); ) {             
            String inputLine;               
            while((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println("Received message : " + inputLine + " from " + sc.toString());   
            }
        } catch(IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Error : " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

When I launch the server and then the client i see that it works fine, but when I stop brutally the server before the end of the counter at client side, I don't see any exception raised on client side and it continues like if the server is still there. I would like to raise an exeption when the server is not there anymore.

Comment: When you say you stopped "brutally" the server, does this mean that your server failed to close down the connection cleanly?  That might be part of your problem here, as the client wouldn't have gotten the message that the connection was being closed.

Comment: Funny thing out `PrintWriter`, it doesn't actually generate a `IOException` (when calling `println`), instead, it changes it's internal "error" state.  You then need to call `checkError` to determine if something went wrong or not.  Personally, I would look towards a different writer, maybe a `BufferedWriter` or something which would actually generate an `Exception` when writing failed - but that's me

Comment: by brutally i mean i kill the server process. I have also tried with BufferedWriter and it gives the same result (BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new PrintWriter(sc.getOutputStream(), true)); out.write("number " + i + " transmitted !"); but it gives the same result, no exception raised.

Comment: DON'T use `PrintWriter` - it is consuming the error - maybe `new BufferedWriter(new InputStreamReader(sc.getOutputStream()))` or something